# how to update a variable in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i just started learning actionscript 3 and i have a question. I am trying to create a game but i am not sure on how to create a global update for a variable? for example if i put this:

```
    myNumber+=1;
    txt.text = myNumber.toString();
```

It only updates once and stops when the game starts. I would like a constant update. How is this possible? is there an update() method this needs to go under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.EnterFrame, HandleGameLoop);

function HandleGameLoop(e:Event):void
{
    // Everything in here will be called Every frame.
}
```

I suggest you look at a few tutorials given the questions you have asked.
Here is a great one about games. It goes through the process from start to finish.

http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/

Comment: Try to avoid using the enterFrame event as this works off of the frame rate set for the swf which can be changed and could potentially mess up data. You best bet would be to use the Timer Class.

Comment: He just wants to keep the text field up to date. Running the game timer off the frame rate would be a huge mistake I agree. But just updating a textfield etc either way would work. The problem with times in flash is if you start lagging really bad (way to much junk going on and your frame rate drops) the timers keep working at the proper time so everything is happening way to close together for your given framerate.

Comment: A mixture of the two is what I usually use in game prototypes. Where everything is done off of a time slice. Instead of moving x every frame I move x * timeslice. so that when the frame rate drops everything stays smooth.

Comment: an EnterFrame event is well suited in this context (animations).